# How to calculate UIScrollview content offset on zoom?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I read some answers on stackoverflow about this but it doesn't work for me.

I have a scrollView of frame (0,0,320,460), Zoom Scale is 4.0. I place an UIImageView at frame (125,20,70,70).

By hitTesting, I am checking tap point is inside UIImageView or not. Its working fine when zoom scale is 1. When I zoom UIScrollView (zoom scale can be any between 1 to 4) hit test is not working.

Please give suggestions.

Comment: What do you mean by saying hit test is not working?

Comment: I'm not able to get tap detection on UIImageView. Getting tap detection outside of UIImageView.

Comment: You can convert tap location to image view (`[touch locationInView:imageView]`) and check that it's inside bounds rectangle.

Comment: UITapGestureRecognizer can detection tap in UIImageView